# "sudo gparted" is not working. It says, "The process gpartedbin is already running. Only one gpartedbin process is permitted."

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, 18.10

[image: Screenshot image:]

**This is Ubuntu 18.10 dual booted with Windows 10.**
For some reason, I have never been able to launch Gparted clicking its app icon. So  I have to launch it through terminal every-time.

Sometimes it gives this warning:

> tmp.mount doesn't exist.

Sometimes it gives this error:

> The process gpartedbin is already running.
>   Only one gpartedbin process is permitted."

Comment: 1. I think you need not worry about the warning; 2. I guess that `gparted` was run before, and not closed correctly, when 'the process gpartedbin is already running'. What happens if you identify the process: `ps -Af|grep gpartedbin` and kill it? What happens after a reboot? 3. It is a good habit to use `sudo -H` with graphical programs, so `sudo -H gparted`.

Comment: Usually after reboot/shutdown I get: 1. OS cashes a lot. If a wifi dongle is connected, then it try to send error log. And then for some reason it can't and leave me nowhere but to press hard the power button. 2. Os crashes saying "Bad rip value". @sudodus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of pressing the power button (hard shutdown), you can often **reboot gracefully** with `SysRq REISUB` or **shutdown gracefully** with `SysRq REISUO`. This prevents damage to the file system.

  See this link: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

  `SysRq` is often activated with **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>** and then, while those two keys are still pressed, type slowly the letters **R E I S  U B** or **R E I S U O**.
- **The root file system may be damaged**.

  - Boot from another drive, for example an Ubuntu install USB drive or DVD disk.
  - Check that your installed system's root partition is **not** mounted.
  - Now you can check and if necessary repair with

    ```
    sudo e2fsck /dev/sdxn
    ```

    where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, `/dev/sda6` according to your screenshot.

---

Now to what you asked for:

- I think you need not worry about the warning.
- Probably `gparted` was run before, and not closed correctly, when 'the process `gpartedbin` is already running'.

  - Identify the process:

    ```
    ps -Af|grep gpartedbin
    ```

    and try to kill it.

---

- Since you have problems with reboot, please reboot gracefully, and I hope, these problems will disappear.
- It is a good habit to use

  ```
  sudo -H
  ```

  with graphical programs, so

  ```
  sudo -H gparted
  ```

  The reason is that programs, for example editors and file browsers write in configuration files, and with plain `sudo` the configuration of your own user ID can be overwritten by `root` and it stops working for normal use. This will not happen if you use `sudo -H`.

Comment: Thanks, i have heard about "reboot gracefully" method and tried using it before but without "those two keys are still pressed". So never worked. Form now on, i will press those buttons continuously and give it a shot.